# How to avoid minus values in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent a value from going negative in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488761/best-way-to-prevent-a-value-from-going-negative-in-mysql)

Guys I am new to here and also to the programming. I am working on an inventory control system. I'll explain my problem using an example. Think my current stock is 500 sales should be reduced from the stock. When I am entering sales amount if I enter 1000 value would be -500. How can i avoid this?? currently I am doing it like this

--php pseudo code---

```
if(stock > sales)
 { stock - sales}

else
 {error}
```

my data type is float(10,2).

Can I avoid this problem in any other way? I don't know whether my question is clear or not. (Sorry for my bad language skills)

Answer (score 3):

Your approach seems fine, but you should note that you may have a race condition if multiple threads can operate on the data at the same time. You can use transactions with the isolation level set to serializable to ensure that two threads do not decrease the value at the same time.

You could also make the column type `unsigned int` to be sure that it will never contain a negative value, but you should still handle this condition explicitly.

Comment: +1, you really should check before hand to see if subtracting is a valid operation, and then return an error to the user if it isn't going to be.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql allows numeric column types to be UNSIGNED which basically means it cannot be negative.
I couldn't find a reference just about it so try going through [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temp variable setted to 0 and populate it when it's actually positive, example:

```
$res=0;
if($stock > $sales)
 $res=$stock-$sales
```

or simply:

```
$res = $stock > $sales ? $stock - $sales: 0
```

in this way $res will never be under 0